# Error in ProC code execution

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle10g, proc

I'm trying to execute below Pro*C code and compilation was successful. when I execute the program, `SELECT` statement in the code is being failed and `sqlca.sqlcode` is `-1012`. I couldn't find what this error means. Can someone help me out what exactly I'm doing wrong in this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sqlca.h>

#define SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS
// EXEC SQL INCLUDE sqlca.h;
void sqlerror()
{
printf("In error\n");
printf("SQLCODE:<%d>\n",sqlca.sqlcode);
EXEC SQL ROLLBACK RELEASE;
exit(1);
}
void main()
{
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
char *username="dummy";
char *pwd="dummy";
char *dbname="dbname";
int counter;
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR DO sqlerror();
EXEC SQL CONNECT :username IDENTIFIED BY :pwd at :dbname;
if(sqlca.sqlcode == 0)
{
printf("connected\n");
}
printf("Before SQLCODE:<%d>\n",sqlca.sqlcode);
EXEC SQL SELECT count(1)
    into :counter
  from TEST
  where rownum <3;
printf("SQLCODE:<%d>\n",sqlca.sqlcode);
if(sqlca.sqlcode == 0)
{
   printf("connected2\n");
}
printf("Account number is %d",counter);
EXEC SQL COMMIT RELEASE;
if(sqlca.sqlcode == 0)
{
printf("connection released\n");
}
}
```

After compilation, when I executed the program i got below output

```
connected
Before SQLCODE:<0>
In error
SQLCODE:<-1012>
```

below are compiler options

```
proc iname=sample.pc include=/dbvolume/oracle/product/11.2.0_client_1/rdbms/public sqlcheck=semantics userid=dummy/dummy
gcc -o sample sample.c -I/dbvolume/oracle/product/11.2.0_client_1/precomp/public/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh
```

Comment: I tried your code and i was facing the same error, until i changed the connection to db string a little bit.. EXEC SQL CONNECT :username IDENTIFIED BY :pwd using :tnsentryforthedb; I am using "using" instead of at dbname.

Comment: @pOrinG Thank you very much :) its working now

Comment: Your welcome. Although it fixed your problem, I wont be able to provide the root cause of this issue as I am myself not so sure. Good day.